# Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread. What is happening here?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have another program that I get this error when I do not hit the button but works fine when I do.  This is a simplified version.  This one gets the fault ether way.  When you change the timeout value on pymsgbox to 299 to force a timeout the thread is reported as not alive.

```
import pymsgbox
from threading import Thread
from _thread import interrupt_main
import time


def safety_abort_button():

    result = pymsgbox.alert('FORCE ABORT?', 'IS BOARD SMOKING?', button="YES!", timeout=29900)

    # interrupt the main thread
    if(result == 'YES!'):
        interrupt_main()

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':


    try:
        # start the safety thread
        thread = Thread(target=safety_abort_button)
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(10)
        alive = thread.is_alive()
        print(alive)


    except:
        print('button pushed')
        boo = 1


    exit()
```

I expected this to run clean without the error message.  Would this cause a memory leak?